# TeamCity SVN Checkout Rules pulling files then deleting them

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have the following checkout rules:

```
-:%cit.svn.name%/%cit.svn.path%/sql
-:%cit.svn.name%/%cit.svn.path%/doc
+:%cit.svn.name%/%cit.svn.path%=>.
```

(Note: I've tried these with exclude first as well)

Our SQL path in particular has thousands of files because the DB is also in SVN so I want to exclude it from checkouts on the build server.

When the build (clean) was complete the first time, the doc and sql paths were still on the build agent server but empty, and the checkout process wasn't any faster.

I ran the build again (not clean) and I watched the folders on the agent server and found that EVERYTHING was still pulled down, and this time it was left behind.

Is this a problem with my checkout rules?  I've tried several variations and keep getting more files than needed and it's dragging out the checkout process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, exclude checkout rules for Subversion roots are only effective when server-side checkout is used.

[Related note](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Rules#VCSCheckoutRules-ineffectiveExcludeRulesOnAgent) in TeamCity doc.
[Related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-49571) in TeamCity issue tracker.

Comment: Converting to server side not only did the trick but my checkouts are down to 8 minutes for clean (from 18) and almost instant for simple updates now.  Thanks!